# Examples of Covariance Stationary Time Series

Tags: statistics, economics

I seem to be having trouble in comprehending what it means for a time series to be covariance stationary. Specifically, with the third condition of 
for any $t$ and $h$, $ cov(x_t,x_{t+h})$ only depends on $h$ and not $t$.

Would anyone have any examples of how a time series might be covariance stationary or any examples of non-covariance stationary time series?

I would really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: An independent process (i.e. $(x_t)_t$ an independent collection) is covariance stationary and a time-independent process ( $x_t=x_0$ for all $t$ and $x_0$ not deterministic) is not.

Answer (score 0):

Example of an covariance stationary time series:
Define $X_t=a_ta_{t-1}$ a process with $\{a_t\}$ white noise ($N(0,\sigma^2)$):

\begin{eqnarray*}
cov(X_{t},X_{t+h})& =& cov(a_{t}a_{t-1},a_{t+h}a_{t+h-1})\\
&=& E[a_{t}a_{t-1}a_{t+h}a_{t+h-1}]-E[a_{t}a_{t-1}]E[a_{t+h}a_{t+h-1}] \cdots (*)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

where (by distributional assumption $N(0,\sigma^2$):
$$cov(a_t,a_{t-1})=0=E[a_ta_{t-1}]-E[a_t]E[a_{t-1}]=E[a_ta_{t-1}]-[0][0]$$
$$E[a_ta_{t-1}]=0$$

substituting the last result in $(*)$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
cov(X_{t},X_{t+h})&=& E[a_{t}a_{t-1}a_{t+h}a_{t+h-1}]-[0][0] \\
cov(X_{t},X_{t+h})&=& E[a_{t}a_{t-1}a_{t+h}a_{t+h-1}]
\end{eqnarray*}

case 1 ($h=0$):
\begin{eqnarray*}
cov(X_{t},X_{t+h})&=& E[a_{t}a_{t-1}a_{t}a_{t-1}] \\
cov(X_{t},X_{t+h})&=& E[a_{t}^2a_{t-1}^2]=E[a_{t}^2]E[a_{t-1}^2]=\sigma^2*\sigma^2=\sigma^4.
\end{eqnarray*}

case 2 ($h\neq 0$):
\begin{eqnarray*}
cov(X_{t},X_{t+h})&=& E[a_{t}a_{t-1}a_{t+h}a_{t+h-1}] \\
\text{by independence:}\\
cov(X_{t},X_{t+h})&=& E[a_{t}]E[a_{t-1}]E[a_{t+h}]E[a_{t+h-1}]=0*0*0*0=0.
\end{eqnarray*}

$\rightarrow Cov(X_t,X_{t+h})=\sigma^4*\mathbb{1}_{\{h=0\}}$
so, the covariance funcion only depends on $h$ and not $t$.